# LUKS auto decryption with key file fails, please help me debug

Tags: raspberry-pi, luks, reboot

I have a Raspberry Pi with attached, via USB, HDD drive inside Orico chassis with a separate power source. I encrypted this drive with the command:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda
```

Then, I created key file with command:

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=32 count=1 of=/home/ubuntu/luks/luks.key
```

added this file as second key with command:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda /home/ubuntu/luks/luks.key
```

and added this line to `/etc/crypttab`:

```
vault /dev/sda none
```

I think that I did everything to make this drive auto decrypt during system boot, but that doesn't happen. I have to do it manually after every reboot. The other thing that bothers me is output from `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda`. 
I would expect two slots being on status "enabled", but I don't see it in the output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Temporary failure in name resolution
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          4
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           ab24c6e5-9286-4e6d-a874-29755338afa1
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2i
    Time cost:  4
    Memory:     270573
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       b8 50 50 6c b2 54 45 ea 36 45 66 1d 61 d1 e9 94 
                87 7c 67 d3 a8 f3 3b 54 04 b6 46 7b 25 0d d2 89 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
  1: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2i
    Time cost:  4
    Memory:     268825
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       55 e6 be a8 55 45 61 3c 1b 6e 6d 7a b3 70 40 32 
                fc 4f 95 71 f0 13 52 c7 a1 69 cb 73 66 0b a9 6f 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:290816 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 39527
    Salt:       62 9b 83 b6 04 f3 b0 aa 36 21 bc bf 28 aa 1d 3c 
                ad 89 8a 5c 0d 7a d2 f4 0f 6e d4 09 b2 33 0b d4 
    Digest:     45 42 fc 30 22 95 12 26 3f 78 8c 56 d7 b0 c3 d9 
                10 4e 32 99 93 3c 10 48 a3 df ab 89 77 89 14 1f
```

Do you think that this problem might be related to the fact that the HDD is connected as a USB drive? 
As mentioned previously, opening this LUKS volume manually works fine. 
Please help me debug this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the key file in `/etc/crypttab`, if you put `none` there, it will be interpreted as "ask for passphrase".

From `man crypttab`:

> The third field specifies the encryption password. If the field is not present or the password is set to "none" or "-", the password has to be manually entered during system boot. Otherwise, the
> field is interpreted as an absolute path to a file containing the encryption password.

Note that `luksAddKey` doesn't mean you are adding a new passwordless key slot to the LUKS device, you are adding a new keyslot protected with a new password or in your case a passphrase read from a file `/home/ubuntu/luks/luks.key` -- this is not the key used by LUKS/dm-crypt, it's just a "binary password", you still need to provide it when unlocking/opening the LUKS device.

Changing your crypttab entry to

```
vault /dev/sda /home/ubuntu/luks/luks.key
```

should do the trick.

The `luksDump` output is ok, it changed with LUKS version 2 and it no longer prints the `Key Slot X: ENABLED/DISABLED` line (for LUKS 2, it still prints it for LUKS 1).

Comment: thank you so much :) everything works fine now. I just have one more question - Is it possible to define drive by label name? I have noticed, that when I plug drive to another usb port, than it gets name /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sda as defined in /etc/crypttab

Comment: The label is a weak identifier. You should get the UUID of the partition (blkid /dev/sdX) and instead of `/dev/sda` in the crypttab file, use `UUID=2505567a-9e27-4efe-a4d5-15ad146c258b`, using the UUID you found with `blkid`.